# How to align 3 select in a single row

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using the following plugin

abecoffman/birthdaypicker

This generates the following html code automatically

```
<fieldset class='birthday-picker'>
 <select class='birth-year' name='birth[year]'></select>
 <select class='birth-month' name='birth[month]'></select>
 <select class='birth-day' name='birth[day]'></select>
 <input type='hidden' name='birthdate' />
</fieldset>
```

it looks like following. I want all the select boxes in a single row.Did anybody came across similar situation.

[image]

Comment: what version of Bootstrap are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
.birthday-picker select
{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
.birthday-picker select{
    float:left
}
```